# Are there any security implications for storing a user's email and password in their local storage?

Tags: redux, react-redux, local-storage, password-protection

In a MERN project, within my redux folder I have a file called userActions.js which has the creator action function that stores a user's email, password, and name within an object in their local storage called userInfo.

```js
export const register = (name, email, password) => async(dispatch) => {
  dispatch(setLoading(true));
  try {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    };

    //if API successful, then data object is returned
    const {
      data
    } = await axios.post('/api/users/register', {
      email,
      password,
      name
    }, config);
    //Successful data object is dispatched and received as payload in slice, reducer userLogin
    dispatch(userLogin(data));
    localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(data));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(
      setError(
        error.response && error.response.data ?
        error.response.data.message :
        error.message ?
        error.message :
        'An unexpected error has occured. Please try again later.'
      )
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: Yes. Don’t do that